# Calculate cross-product of every three consecutive points in a list and check whether all cross products have same signs or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, polygon

I created a list of vertices of a polygon, using a 'Point' class and 'Polygon' class.. Now, to check the type of the polygon, that whether it is a 'concave; or 'convex' polygon, I want to calculate the cross-products of **every three consecutive points** present in the list of vertices. As an example, consider a list : **vertices = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6]**. Considering this list, the sequence should be p1,p2,p3...p2,p3,p4...p3,p4,p5...p4,p5,p6...and the p5,p6,p1. I mean, the last cross product will be between last 2 elements and 1st element of the list because polygon is a closed figure.
Then after calculating, the program should check whether all cross products are -ive (negative) or all are +ive (positive) because these are the conditions for the polygon to be **convex**.

```
class Polygon:
    def __init__(self,*vertices):
        self.vertices=[Polygon.Point(v[0],v[1]) for v in vertices]

    def CrossProduct(self, A, B, C):
        return (B.x - A.x) * (C.y - B.y) -(B.y - A.y) * (C.x - B.x)

    @property
    def shape(self):    #Method for determining the type of polygon i.e. Convex or concave
        # if (all cross product >=0 or all cross products <=0):
            #return 'Convex'
        # return 'Concave'

    class Point:
        def __init__(self,x,y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

### MAIN PROGRAM ###
poly1 = Polygon((3,4), (5,11), (12,8), (9,5), (5,6))  #Concave Polygon
poly2 = Polygon((5.09,5.80), (1.68,4.90), (1.48,1.38), (4.76,0.10), (7.00,2.83))  #Convex Polygon
print(poly1.shape)
print(poly2.shape)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create all needed 3-tuples using zip(..) and check them with all(..):

```
class Polygon:
    def __init__(self,*vertices):
        self.vertices=[Polygon.Point(v[0],v[1]) for v in vertices]

    def CrossProduct(self, A, B, C):
        return (B.x - A.x) * (C.y - B.y) -(B.y - A.y) * (C.x - B.x)

    @property
    def shape(self):  #Method for determining the type of polygon i.e. Convex or concave
        p0 = self.vertices[0:1]
        # debugging printout of points that are going to be checked
        points = list(zip(self.vertices, self.vertices[1:], self.vertices[2:] + p0))
        print(*points)
        print ([self.CrossProduct(*p) for p in points])

        if all(self.CrossProduct(*p) >= 0 for p in points) or all(
            self.CrossProduct(*p) < 0 for p in points):
            return "Convex"
        return "Concave"

    class Point:
        def __init__(self,x,y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

        def __str__(self):
            return f"({self.x}, {self.y})"

        def __repr__(self):
            return str(self)

poly1 = Polygon((3,4), (5,11), (12,8), (9,5), (5,6))  # Concave 
poly2 = Polygon((5.09,5.80), (1.68,4.90), (1.48,1.38), (4.76,0.10), (7.00,2.83))  
print(poly1.shape) # Concave 
print(poly2.shape) # Convex
```

Output:

```
((3, 4), (5, 11), (12, 8)) ((5, 11), (12, 8), (9, 5)) ((12, 8), (9, 5), (5, 6)) ((9, 5), (5, 6), (3, 4))
[-55, -30, -15, 10]
Concave

((5.09, 5.8), (1.68, 4.9), (1.48, 1.38)) ((1.68, 4.9), (1.48, 1.38), (4.76, 0.1)) ((1.48, 1.38), (4.76, 0.1), (7.0, 2.83)) ((4.76, 0.1), (7.0, 2.83), (5.09, 5.8))
[11.823200000000002, 11.8016, 11.8216, 11.8671]
Convex
```

Comment: `if any(self.CrossProduct(*p) < 0 for p in points) and any(
            self.CrossProduct(*p) > 0 for p in points):` may small faster

Comment: @정도유 You do not handle the `0` case. It might be faster.  `all` will terminate as soon as one element does not statisfy the condition and then check the second part. yours will terminate as soon as 1 element statisfies the condition then check the other (opposit one) and also terminate as soon as any statisfies it. The "speed" depends on the data presented (after fixing the 0 issue) and I would consider optimizing that if and only if I can measure a bottleneck in that exact location.

Answer (score 1):

After isolating the problem a bit, something like that came to my mind:

```
pp = [(3,4), (5,11), (12,8), (9,5), (5,6)]

pp = pp + pp[:(len(pp) % 3 - 1)]

print(pp)

c = list(zip(pp, pp[1:], pp[2:]))

def cross_product(p):
    print(p)
    pass

for pt in c:
    cross_product(pt)
```

Which yields:

```
[(3, 4), (5, 11), (12, 8), (9, 5), (5, 6), (3, 4)]
((3, 4), (5, 11), (12, 8))
((5, 11), (12, 8), (9, 5))
((12, 8), (9, 5), (5, 6))
((9, 5), (5, 6), (3, 4))
```

So, first of all you have to 'pad' the initial list a bit so that it wraps properly - the length has to be divisible by 3 so that we can pack it into groups of 3 points.

After that, it's a matter of simple zip between 3 consecutive elements and a cross-product calculation.